# The data is not saving in db using Pop-up Window after publish the application in Local host mvc4?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have one issue that is the data is not saving in db using Pop-up Window after Local host. I will explain my issue clearly.I Have one view called Customer. In that I have one field called Area and also  i keep one add button near to that field.

**Area**

[image]

when i click the + button it will open the popup window. The pop window is mention below

**Area Pop winodw**

[image]

When i build and run the application and open this view and click the +  button and enter all the details and click the save button it saving the value in db. All are working fine. But after  i publish my applciation and open this view and click the + button it open the pop-up window. Untill this its working fine. But when i enter all the details and click the save button it not saving the data in Db. This is the issue. After my publish my application the datat is not saving in Db using pop-up window. But in Normal run it is perfectly working.

After Publishing the popup window

[image]

its working upto
          $('#AreaID').append($('').val(data).text(Area));

but the saving is not saving in db. But all are working fine in normal run  that is savinf data using pop-up is perfectly working in normal application running. But after i host my application in local host thi spopup window is not correctly working.

My View Code

```
  <div id="Area">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Area, new { @class = "control-label" })<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-opener" style="float: right; Width: 28px; height: 28px; ">+</a>
  <div id="dialog-modal" title="Add New Area" style="display:none">
  <div class="box-body">
  <span class="red">*</span>
  @Html.Label("Area", new { @class = "control-label" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Area, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "AreaName" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Area)

  @Html.Label("City")
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a City", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text", id = "City" })
   <div class="box-footer">
   <input id="Button1" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Save" onclick="SaveArea()" />
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   @Html.DropDownList("AreaID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control required" })

   </div>
   </div>
```

**My J query Code**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function () {
     debugger
     $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width: 500,
        maxHeight: 400,
        draggable: true,
        dialogClass: 'main-dialog-class',
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000

        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        },
        open: function () {
            var closeBtn = $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
            closeBtn.append('<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>');
        },
        close: function () {
            var closeBtn = $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
            closeBtn.html('');
        },
    });
    $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
        debugger
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
    });
});
function onSuccess() {
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog("close");
}


         function SaveArea() {
            debugger
            var url = '@Url.Action("Customer", "AddAreaInfo", new { area = "Sales" })';
            var customerContact = $('#modalform').serialize(); // must have a <form id="modalform"> in the popup
            var Area = $("#AreaName").val();
            var CityID = $("#City").val();
            var AreaAdd = { "Area": '' + Area + '', "CityID": CityID };
            $.post("/Sales/Customer/AddAreaInfo", AreaAdd, function (data) {
                  $('#AreaID').append($('<option><option>').val(data).text(Area));
                 $('#AreaID').val(data);
                alert ("Success")
            });
        }


        $(function () {
            $.ajax(
             '@Url.Action("GetCity", "Customer", new { Area = "Sales" })',{
                     type: "GET",
                     datatype: "Json",
                     success: function (data) {
                     $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                     $('#City').append('<option value="' + value.CityID + '">' +value.DisplayName + '</option>');
               });
              }
            });
         });
```

**Controller**

```
      public JsonResult AddAreaInfo(CustomerViewModel objareaVM)
       {
       var objAreaID = Guid.NewGuid();
       ViewBag.CityID = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityID", "DisplayName", objareaVM.CityID);

       var ObjArea = new Area()
       {
           AreaID = objAreaID,
           DisplayName = objareaVM.Area,
           PrintName = objareaVM.Area,
           CityID = objareaVM.CityID,
           IsActive = true,
           IsDeleted = false,
           CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
           EditedDate = DateTime.Now,
           LastActiveOn = DateTime.Now,
           RowID = Guid.NewGuid(),
           CreatedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
           EditedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
           OfflineMode = false,
           OfflineID = Guid.NewGuid()
       };

       db.Areas.Add(ObjArea);
       db.SaveChanges();
       ModelState.Clear();
       return Json(objAreaID);

   }     

  public JsonResult GetCity()
  {
      return Json(db.Cities.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I itself clear my issue . I like to share my answer . why it is not saving in db is the path to controller in j-query is not corrrect.

Finally I correct my j-query code

The answer is

**J query Code**

```
function SaveArea() {
            debugger
            var url = '@Url.Action("AddAreaInfo", "Customer", new { area = "Sales" })';
            var customerContact = $('#modalform').serialize(); // must have a <form id="modalform"> in the popup
            var Area = $("#AreaName").val();
            var CityID = $("#City").val();
            var AreaAdd = { "Area": '' + Area + '', "CityID": CityID };
            $.post(url, AreaAdd, function (data) {
                  $('#AreaID').append($('<option><option>').val(data).text(Area));
                 $('#AreaID').val(data);
                alert ("Success")
            });
        }
```

Before I gave my path as

```
  var url = '@Url.Action(" Customer", "AddAreaInfo", new { area = "Sales" })';
```

Now i change that to

```
  var url = '@Url.Action("AddAreaInfo", "Customer", new { area = "Sales"})';
```

So the issue got cleared and finally  it save the data in DB.